# how do I set ngbTooltip in an angular attribute directive

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have an angular attribute directive and want to set a tooltip with ngbTooltip, but my code does not work:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
  selector: '[app-mybutton]',
  templateUrl: './mybutton.html'
})
export class MyButtonComponent {

  constructor (renderer: Renderer2, el: ElementRef) {
    const nativeElement = el.nativeElement;
    renderer.setAttribute (nativeElement, 'ngbTooltip', 'some text');
  }
}
```

The attribute is set but no tooltip is shown.
How can this be accomplished?